# Load txt file, read values and sum

Tags: sum, octave, element

I am new in Octave and I would like to create the following things:

1. A .txt file with 10 elements = 10 values
2. Load this file and read the data (values)
3. A function to add all these values
4. Return the total

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there specific problems with the implementation?

Comment: Now, start to use Octave but I do not know if it is possible to load the values of elements. For example I have a text  file with x1=1, x2=2 .... x10=10 .. How to add 1+2+3+..+10?

Comment: You can read files with `fscanf`, see http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Formatted-Input.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file called "in.txt" that looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Then read it into Octave and sum the elements using something like this (assuming Octave's working directory is the same as where you saved the file, use "pwd" to confirm):

```
load("in.txt"); sum(x)
```